# Database architecture - Have 2 seperate columns or 1

Tags: database

Okey, context:

I have a system that requires to do a monthly, weekly and dayly reports.

Architecture **A**:
3 tables:
1) Monthly reports
2) Weekly reports
3) Daily reports

Architecture **B**:
1 table:
1) Reports: With extra column `report_type`, with values: "monthly", "weekly", "daily".

Which one would be more performant and why?

Comment: Why are you wanting to store data in the format of reports in the database?

Comment: @HappyCoding , maybe it's just a logging table to know when the reports are run. I've done something similar.

Comment: Better question, would you please tell us what columns you're planning to have in these tables or table?

Comment: We store reports, to know the correct data in the past. Both of tables would contain integer values(pagesviews, sessions, etc) and 6 string values(like top countries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common method I use to do this is use two tables, following similarly to your B approach. One table would be as you describe with report data and an extra column, but instead of hard coding the values, this column would hold an id to a reference table. The reference table would then hold the names of these values. This set up allows you to easily reference the intervals with other tables should you need that later on, but also makes name updates much more efficient. Changing the name of say "Monthly" to "Month" would require one update here, vs n updates if you stored the string in your report table.

Sample structure:

```
report_data | interval_id
xxxx        | 1

interval_id | name
1           | Monthly
```

As a side note, you would rarely want to take your first approach, approach A, due to how it limits changing the interval type of entered data. If all of a sudden you want to change half of your Daily entries to Weekly entries, you need to do n/2 deletes and n/2 inserts, which is fairly costly especially if you start introducing indexes. In general tables should describe types of data (ie Reports) and columns should describe that type (ie How often a report happens)

Comment: We are not planing to change past report data. But yeah, i am thinking about plan B too.

Comment: You should always try to future proof a database when possible since changing the setup later can be extremely difficult and time consuming. But obviously if you know the absolute setup of your database you should refine to that.